# "Objective" idealism: what is the reason for believing the perception is the perceived?

Tags: idealism

I'm looking at Objective Idealism:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_idealism

This includes some German idealists. Maybe all idealists other than Berkeley?

So the way I understand it, this has 2 tenets:

1. Only one mind
2. Objective world is somehow this one mind itself

I'm having trouble understanding the full meaning of 2), as well as motivations behind it.

For example, say an objective idealist fully accepts the laws of physics as operating in the objective world. The objective world being within the perceiver means that the laws of physics somehow only exist within the perceiver's mind? Does it mean that if all beings stopped being conscious of physics, it will stop operating? Or if we collectively forget about a chair, will cease to exist?

Comment: **IF** only mind exists, the "law of the mind" are the law of the world. See Peirce's quotation: "that matter is effete mind, inveterate habits becoming physical laws "

Comment: Wikipedia is not always this bad, but "only one mind" is just bizarre. I am not even sure that Leibniz falls under that with his monads, and that Berkeley does not, all his minds are embedded into God's. The label  "objective idealism" is vague and often misleading, [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/idealism/#Intr) is not using it. When it is used it is by loose conjunction, there is objective reality and what it is made of is more like mind than matter in its properties. It does not have to be one mind, or even minds as we think of them normally, can be some vaguely "mental" substrate.

Comment: Throughout history there've been some mystiques believe the oneness possesses one holographic holy symbol to enfold all the info of this world, and the world was thus created from our point of view while actually it was only this master symbol to be conceived by the oneness. So we *do* while the oneness *conceives*... Everything is from a prior and axiomatized. This kind of Parmenidean *illusory* ontology/epistemology dichotomy may be perhaps closer to your objective idealism above.